# Continuous Background Sound

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

How can I implement a continuous background sound in page that doesn't interrupt when the user moves from one page to another without using iframe?

Comment: uuuhhhhhhhhhhgggggggggggggg

Comment: On behalf of the internet, can I just say, please don't.

Comment: I just had to upvote all these comments :-)

Comment: Are you asking how to play a sound or how to immediately thwart users from returning to your site?

Comment: Why do you think users would want this? Whenever I get to a site with embedded music - I leave!

Comment: OMG... Really this is one of the funniest questions in stackoverflow.. :)

Comment: Still, it's better to have the audio uninterrupted, instead of starting from the beginning with every click. But still, no, you cannot do it without frames or iframes.

Comment: Guys I know, it's for a client of me, he's still even using Tables in his design !!!

Answer (score 0):

use a trick, if having frameset is not an issue for you, construct your page with a frameset and use one frame for background (no size) where you play the sound and other (full 100%x100%) where you can navidate. This has also the advantage of hidding your navigation URL leaving just the site url on nav bar.

Comment: Frames *and* background sounds? Is it 1996? Where did I park my De Lorean.

Comment: Guys I know, it's for a client of me, he's still even using Tables in his design !!!

Comment: @Rory McCrossan: still waiting for that frameless solution because i'm here to learn too

Answer (score 0):

If you are insane, you could set an event listener on the `timeupdate` event of the `<audio>` element and store the `currentTime` in localStorage (or a cookie).  Then, when you load a page, read that value and set the `currentTime` again.  However, I imagine writing to localStorage dozens of times per second might be bad (but I won't make any performance claims until I test it!).

However, this solution requires a mordern browser with `audio` and `localStorage` support.